# How can I change a turning lathe's spindle o-ring?

Tags: lathe

I bought an old turning lathe ( **Żebrak TOS S32**) but there is problem with the **o-ring** of it's **spindle**.

I have opened the lathe and don't know how to take out the spindle shaft and replace the damaged o-ring with a new o-ring.

The following pictures show the part in question:

[image: Żebrak TOS S32]

So as you can see from the pictures, how could I separate the spindle shaft from it's gear wheel to remove the  spindle shaft and change it's o-ring?

The manual for the lathe can be found here:

[Żebrak TOS S32 manual](http://www.tumlikovo.cz/wp-content/uploads/2010/manualy/manS32.zip)

[Żebrak TOS S32 manual in 4shared](https://www.4shared.com/zip/p8PFn9Dtca/manS32.html)

And, I also found this:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't supposed to leak oil? Older British lathes (MUCH older than this!) used "total loss lubrication", the technical term for "dribbles oil". Precision and stiffness were paramount, niceties like not peeing on the carpet weren't so important.  (TOS have a very good reputation by the way)

Answer (score 0):

The oil leak you have is only from the front cover plate. The oil is from the front spindle bearing draining into the cover plate. This proves that oil is being supplied to the front bearing. This cover can be sealed by making a gasket from some 0.4mm gasket paper.

I know this is an old question that you posted but did you find a solution? I would also like the technical information regarding the removal of the spindle in order to replace the bearings.

Cheers,
Craig

Comment: a little-known fact is that the british were caught flat-footed when the americans invented recirculating pressure lubrication, which rendered total-loss lubrication systems obsolete. The british then were forced to advance their technology by inventing something called the *oil leak* and patenting it. Harley-davidson then were forced to license the oil leak patent from the british! this is little-known because I made it all up.